# How to make the width fit to text in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-data-studio

While preparing a regular table, all the text (header and body) gets cut off.

Is there a way to have the width auto fit to text?

There is an option of **Wrap Text**, but that's not what I want.

[image: Text cut off]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out if you stretch the table's overall width wide enough, then right click it, then the Fit to Width option doesn't cut off titles.

[image: Fit to data]

Comment: It's called "Resize columns" > "Fit to DATA", but yeah, thanks!